# Broadcom network modules fail to install in new kernels. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

I've been having this issue for a while now and I'm not sure how best to resolve it.

Basically, if my system gets a new kernel it fails to install the broadcom network modules for the new kernel.

Usually I don't notice unless I restart the server. Then I end up having to hook up a monitor and keyboard and boot into an older kernel and either remove the new kernel or install the drivers for the new kernel.

This is an annoyance I'd rather not have and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried marking linux-headers-generic and linux-image-generic for hold with apt-mark, but it appears I'm still getting kernels for some reason.

```
root@olympus:/boot# apt-mark showhold
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic
```

Either I need to automatically get network drivers on new kernel installs or I need to just stop getting new kernels altogether. Either is fine with me. Could anyone offer some suggestions on a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I modified my grub to boot to a pre-specified kernel that has the drivers. Now if a new kernel is installed it doesn't matter, I won't be booting to it by default anyways. Followed the instructions found here: https://kowalczyk.me/change-default-kernel-in-ubuntu-18-04/